# Trust Anchor not found for Android under proxy connection

Tags: android, ssl, expo, lets-encrypt, http-proxy

I developed a simple Android app using Expo SDK that communicates with my server via HTTPS (using Axios if it matters). I have bought the domain and use a LetsEncrypt certificate configurated in NGINX that has an A+ score in the Qualys SSL Test. The app works well with most of my clients except one that uses it under a network proxy that I don't have access to.
Every time the app tries to request the servers I get the error:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Which according to this article https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl?hl=en-us can happen when "The CA that issued the server certificate was unknown", "The server certificate wasn't signed by a CA, but was self signed", "The server configuration is missing an intermediate CA" which is not the case since it works with every other client.

This client uses Android 8.1 and I've already checked in “Encryption & credentials” settings that "DST Root CA X3" (which is the anchor for LetsEncrypt) is listed as a trusted root certificate in the devices.

For test purposes, I also have developed a version of my app that does not use HTTPS and it works fine even under the proxy connection.

Am I missing something here? What else could be causing this problem? Any ideas on how to replicate it? Thank you!